# Laravel Passport Token Database creation error

Tags: oracle, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

DB: Oracle

When Laravel Passport is trying to persist the new Token for the User it gives following error and not creating any token.

> Error Code : 1722 Error Message : ORA-01722: Invalid Number : 145
>   Statement : insert into "OAUTH_AUTH_CODES" ("ID", "USER_ID",
>   "CLIENT_ID", "SCOPES", "REVOKED", "EXPIRES_AT") values (:p0, :p1, :p2,
>   :p3, :p4, :p5) returning "ID" into :p6 Bindings :
>   [da3315abd6a4fe597465898a76feb95fdf8e8116ee64c3889516842a6fa7418e4cf3e030fb8f3445,434,1,[],0,2018-11-22
>   13:00:44,0]

Not sure if its an oracle issue, or if I am doing something wrong with the Passport setup, but don't think there are lot of things where it could go wrong while setup.

For me it seems there is an additional 0 at the end, not sure why this happen. Anyone had a similar issue so please help?

Comment: How r u trying to create the new token ?

Comment: Can you please provide some code on how r u doing.